# Heroku PostgreSQL - could not send SSL negotiation packet: Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku

I'm using Heroku's Postgres add-on in one of my NodeJS apps. The code seems to work but any connections to the database using [this](https://node-postgres.com/) module hangs and never responds with neither a success or a failure.

To investigate the issue, I tried connecting to the database through my terminal using `pgcli <db url>` but got the following error:

`could not send SSL negotiation packet: Resource temporarily unavailable`.

Further details:

- Heroku's console shows that the database is healthy, up, and running.
- Last time I used the database (around 3 months ago) it was working perfectly.
- Any newly created databases from the same add-on work as expecting.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you find any way to solve this?

Comment: @artur99 Unfortunately not, I ended up deleting the resource and creating a new database. Make sure to create a backup then use it to insert the old data to the new db.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to heroku settings, find your environmental variables.
2. Find the DATABASE_URL variable, copy its value
3. Go to your project add .env file and add the environmental variable there
4. Install and follow instructions on env module .e.g https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv
5. Add your connection config

**.env**

```
DATABASE_URL=verylongstring
```

**index.js**

```
require('dotenv').config()

const pg = require('pg'

const pgPool = new pg.Pool({
  connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
  ssl: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false
  }
})
```

If your using github or some other service to store your code make sure to not send the .env file with you since its only for local development. Heroku has the environmental variables in your app.

**.gitignore**

.env

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, this is exactly what I'm doing code-wise. This works with any database URL I use except the one I'm attempting to connect to. The problem is in the database itself as far as I see, not the code.

Comment: Have you checked if the connection string has changed? There might be a new connection string in heroku for the database.

Comment: I did check, it is the same left untouched for a few months and when I came back this happened. I've tried upgrading `pg` to the latest version but that still didn't help.

Comment: Have tried connecting through a client like pgAdmin4?

Comment: I tried using DBeaver. The response was `User does not have CONNECT privilege`